# android application with server as j2ee

Tags: android

I am new to android, and i m working on an app dat needs some server side code.For that i m thinking to use J2ee, now tell me(the concept n requirement only) so that i can send the data like log in form details to server from sqlite of android, and after some processing i want to send notifications to client devices.( i know for that i have to use google C2Dm).

But the actual problem is how do i test these things on my pc,before publishing the app.
also tell me the tools dat i need to install beside android sdk , and the language that i need to learn that can synchronize or simply send android data to server.

I have seen that when we register in websites they send us message for conformation. which technology is used here.

and last after my app is ready how to publish it, the whole process(including where i will be putting my server database and server code).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would like to suggest you to implementing a REST based web service in Java EE server. You can use JSONObject to consume this restful service.

An example for using the JSONObject with REST is given in the link:

https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/implementing_restful_web_services_in

http://javapostsforlearning.blogspot.in/2013/04/restful-web-service-tutorial.html

and to call Web Services from Android

http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr

beside this lot of stuff you can find out through google!!

for needed tools visit

http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html